# Safari is not working on Windows 7 properly

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, browser, safari-5

Safari is almost dead on my Windows 7 **64bit** PC

[image]

I have uninstalled then re-installed the latest version but still not working.

I also followed all possible suggestion from this article. http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-10354948-263.html

Please help.

Comment: _"Almost dead"_? What does that mean?

Comment: You are not supplying enough information and not answering questions, so why post here ?

Comment: The browser opens but it doesn't open any website

Comment: Are you only having this problem in Safari? Do other browsers work? Do you have a proxy set up?

Comment: Yes other browser works fine And for  safari I've followed all possible fixes from this http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-10354948-263.html

Comment: @metal gear solid, this seems to be a pretty common problem that is spread across multiple platforms. And as far as I can tell, there's no real fix. Apple states "Your DNS server(s) or your router may be affected by DNS prefetching in Safari 5.0.1 or later". So there you have it...

Comment: @MarcusEkwall - I've changed My ISP's DNS to open DNS but still no improvement

Answer (score 1):

Googled around for a bit and found out that this is a fairly common problem that is spread across multiple platforms.

Apple support states that "Your DNS server(s) or your router may be affected by DNS prefetching in Safari 5.0.1 or later". This is due to Safari 5.0's DNS prefetching mechanism, which appears to send more requests than allowed by some ISPs. This issue may also cause problems with some routers.

Steps to disable DNS-prefetching:

1. Open the run dialog with WIN+R
2. Execute the following command (including quotes):

   ```
   "\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Apple\Apple Application Support\defaults.exe" write com.apple.safari WebKitDNSPrefetchingEnabled -boolean false
   ```
3. Restart Safari

To re-enable DNS-prefetching:

1. Open the run dialog with WIN+R
2. Execute the following command (including quotes):

   ```
   "\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Apple\Apple Application Support\defaults.exe" delete com.apple.safari WebKitDNSPrefetchingEnabled
   ```
3. Restart Safari

Comment: I tried #2 but no improvement

Comment: I follwed all steps. still doesn't work

Comment: Then I guess you're out of luck. You'll be better off running Google Chrome instead :)